# show second level of sitemap in site navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation, sitemap

I have a sitemap like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap>
  <siteMapNode title="Home" >
    <siteMapNode title="Services" >
      <siteMapNode title="Training" url="~/Training.aspx"/>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

now I wanna to show second level of sitemap in separate division.

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="menu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"> 
    <asp:HyperLink ID="menu_items" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Repeater>
<div class="separator"></div>
//Here must child Node(s) displayed
//e.g. return <a href="~Training.aspx">Training</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the children for the Basic Reporting, Filtering Reports, and Customized Formatting SiteMapNodes, we can add another Repeater to the initial Repeater's ItemTemplate. This second Repeater will be bound to the SiteMapNode instance's ChildNodes property, like so:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="menu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>

            <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>'>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

These two Repeaters result in the following markup (some markup has been removed for brevity):

```
<li>
    <a href="/Code/BasicReporting/Default.aspx">Basic Reporting</a>
    <ul>
       <li>
          <a href="/Code/BasicReporting/SimpleDisplay.aspx">Simple Display</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="/Code/BasicReporting/DeclarativeParams.aspx">Declarative Parameters</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="/Code/BasicReporting/ProgrammaticParams.aspx">Setting Parameter Values</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="/Code/Filtering/Default.aspx">Filtering Reports</a>
    ...
</li>

<li>
    <a href="/Code/CustomFormatting/Default.aspx">Customized Formatting</a>
    ...
</li>
```

taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the starting node in a new SiteMapDataSource, even though I'm not sure, if it's the best approach. I believe it would be a better idea to read all the nodes in code-behind at once, and then use this source to populate the actual page with the data you want where you want it.
The reason for this is that I'm not a huge fan of a mixing the logic (binding some data source to elements certainly is a logical part) with the presentation (html, etc.). Yes, it would be easy just to spam the aspx file with datasources, but I'm not convinced about it being the best approach.